# In Visio, how do I change the size of one page without changing the size of all other pages within the document?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

I'm trying to resize one page to fit a diagram, but whenever I use "Auto Size" or "Fit to Drawing" it changes the size of every page within the file. Is there a way to resize one page without affecting all pages?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to resize one page to fit a diagram, but whenever I use "Auto Size" or "Fit to Drawing" it changes the size of every page within the file. Is there a way to resize one page without affecting all pages?

You mean new pages ? All new pages add with same settings. When you add first page you must disable AutoSize option, and add another pages.
If you apply the AutoSize option to one of the existing pages, this change will not affect other existing pages